# Unable to Fetch ID from PHP to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to build an E-commerce website using PHP and AJAX but I am facing problem when I try to delete items from the cart. I am fetching the cart data from the cart table that is in my database. The fetched data code is shown below. (Please don't care about the variables, they are all in the code I am not pasting here)

```
echo "<tr>
       <td class='p-image'>
        <a href='product-details?id=$fetchProductID'><img alt='' src='$theRealLink'></a>
       </td>
       <td class='p-name'><a href='product-details?id=$fetchProductID'>$theName</a></td>
       <td class='p-amount'>INR $fetchProductUnitPrice</td>
       <td class='p-quantity'><input maxlength='100' type='text' value='$fetchProductQuantity' name='quantity'></td>
       <td class='p-total'><span>INR $fetchedProductTotal </span></td>
       <td class='edit'><a href='javascript:void(0)' id='delete-from-cart' data-id='$fetchProductID'><img src='assets/img/icon/delte.png' alt=''></a>
       </td>
     </tr>";
```

Whenever someone presses the button with the ID of **delete-from-cart**, I run the javascript code that fetched the ID of the product to be deleted from **data-id** attribute. The code is below

```
$('#delete-from-cart').click(function() {
    var deleteID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(deleteID);
});
```

Just alerting for now. The real problem is, say my cart have 3 different items, so I get 3 different buttons to delete them but only the button of the first item in the cart is working i.e. An alert is displayed containing the ID of the product to be deleted.

I am wondering that why only the first button is working and rest all are not working at all ?

Comment: You can't repeat element ID's in a page, they are unique by definition. Use a class instead

Comment: @charlietfl that solved the problem, thanks alot

Comment: @charlietfl if you can help me with this aswell, how can I update the cart view without refreshing ? because it deleted the item but didnt update

Comment: Suggest you create a separate question for that and include your ajax code along with a more specific problem statement

Comment: @charlietfl wont allow me to ask another within 24 hours

Comment: See what happens if you delete this one since it is already resolved